# MYSQL bloquea el SELECT al ejecutarse un UPDATE en un trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Este es el error que recibo

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1442 Can't update table 'cuentas_cobrar' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Si utilizo un id estático en vez de la consulta para obtener el ID de la cuenta a cobrar dentro del **INSERT**, todo funciona normal.

Acá están los 2 procedimientos:

TRIGGER tr_cuentascobrar_nota (En este trigger. se da el problema):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_cuentascobrar_nota AFTER UPDATE
ON nc_factura FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ( NEW.estadoenvio = 1 ) THEN
            INSERT INTO detalle_cuentas_cobrar ( cuenta_cobrar, monto_cancelado,fecha_actualizacion, banco )
            VALUES ( (SELECT (idcuentas_cobrar) FROM cuentas_cobrar WHERE comprobante = NEW.comprobante_id), NEW.Total, NOW(), 20 );
    END IF ;
END;
```

TRIGGER actualizarCuentaCobrar:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualizarCuentaCobrar BEFORE INSERT
ON detalle_cuentas_cobrar FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    UPDATE cuentas_cobrar SET monto_rest  = monto_rest - NEW.monto_cancelado
    WHERE idcuentas_cobrar = NEW.cuenta_cobrar;

    IF ( (SELECT(monto_rest) FROM cuentas_cobrar WHERE idcuentas_cobrar = NEW.cuenta_cobrar )  = 0) THEN
        UPDATE cuentas_cobrar SET estado = 'PAGADO' WHERE idcuentas_cobrar = NEW.cuenta_cobrar;
    END IF ;
END
```

Comment: el trigger no debería usar directamente la tabla `cuentas_cobrar`, sino la pseudo tabla `INSERTED` o `DELETED`

Comment: @Lamak es que la que se inserta es el detalle, no la misma tabla cuentas_cobrar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comenzar, solo deseo mencionar que, aunque no entiendo todo lo que estás tratando de hacer con los triggers, es posible que estás tratando de hacer demasiado con los triggers. Sería bueno evaluar si hay mejores opciones para lo que haces.

Con esto dicho, el error preciso que recibes se debe a la sentencia siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO detalle_cuentas_cobrar ( cuenta_cobrar, monto_cancelado,fecha_actualizacion, banco )
VALUES ( (SELECT (idcuentas_cobrar) FROM cuentas_cobrar WHERE comprobante = NEW.comprobante_id), NEW.Total, NOW(), 20 );
```

La sentencia `INSERT` incluye una consulta a la tabla `cuentas_cobrar`, pero a la vez, el `INSERT` dispara el trigger `actualizarCuentaCobrar` que intenta modificar esa misma tabla. Esta doble acción simultánea con la misma tabla no es permitido.

La solución es de dividir la sentencia `INSERT` en 2:

1. Primero haces la consulta a la tabla `cuentas_cobrar` usando un `SELECT ... INTO` para conservar el resultado.
2. Luego usas el resultado para ejecutar el `INSERT`.

Código (nota que en el `DECLARE` usé el tipo `INT` por escoger uno. Ajusta para que sea el tipo que corresponde a la columna `idcuentas_cobrar`):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_cuentascobrar_nota AFTER UPDATE
ON nc_factura FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE _idcuentas_cobrar INT;

    IF NEW.estadoenvio = 1 THEN
            SELECT idcuentas_cobrar INTO _idcuentas_cobrar
            FROM cuentas_cobrar WHERE comprobante = NEW.comprobante_id;

            INSERT INTO detalle_cuentas_cobrar (cuenta_cobrar, monto_cancelado,fecha_actualizacion, banco)
            VALUES (_idcuentas_cobrar, NEW.Total, NOW(), 20);
    END IF;
END;
```